# Python string indices must be integers from API dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a Dictionary from an API and I'd like to be able to read the key and value, normally I can do it like this: fill['key'], or fill['created_at'] but none work.

```
for fill in last_fill:
    key = fill
    # key = str(fill)
    print(f"key: {key}")
    # value = fill["'"+ key + "'"] # string indices must be integers
    # value = fill["'",key,"'"]


for fill in last_fill:
    print(fill)

# OUTPUTS all the KEYS
# created_at
# product_id
# order_id
# user_id
# ...
```

And this:

```
for key in last_fill:
    print(f"key: {key}") # OUTPUTS: fill: created_at
    fill = last_fill[key]
    print(fill["created_at"]) # and here the ERROR: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `for .. in ...` loop on a dict returns the keys of the dict. So your `fill` variable represents each key.

```py
for key in last_fill:
    fill = last_fill[key]
    print(fill)
```

In your case you don't seem to actually need the key so you could simply do

```py
for fill in last_fill.values():
    print(fill)
```

If you need keys and values

```py
for item in last_fill.items():
    (key, value) = item
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: I thought fill was the " item ", one of the many fills. I tried your code, and it works. Correction from previous message. Was my mistake.

Comment: it prints the fill, but still gives me the error: string indices must be integers

Comment: I adapted my answer to that.

Comment: Have you tried iterating your dict with `values()` (see updated answer) ? You can also use `items()` if you need kay AND value. If the error persists there must another problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Peterrabbit, but both keep in giving me the same error.

Comment: String indices must be integers means that you are trying to get a value at an index in a string so you are likely doing something like `a_dict_key["something"]` instead of `a_dict["something"]`. Maybe update your question with more detail. Show the current state of your code. It can't be a very big problem..

Comment: It could also be useful to know how is formatted you last_fill dict (and each item in it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242899/discussion-between-peterrabbit-and-sebseb).